Thinkpad E16 doesn't recognize fingerprint scanner
I recently bought Lenovo Thinkpad E16 2nd Generation and I am somehow not able to set up fingerprint login on Ubuntu. When I display all connected busses and the devices connected to them (''lsusb"), fingerprint scanner is not in the list. When I go to BIOS, fingerprint scanner is enabled and should work, but doesn't. Any information concerning this topic would be helpful!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please could you explain specifically what you are asking - is the fingerprint scanner not working, and you would like to know how to get it to work?

What Ubuntu version are you using?

I am on a Thinkpad E16 Gen1 and got the fingerprint scanner to work by installing the deb file provided at Lenovo Support. It's listed as compatible with ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 and E15 Gen 4 but it worked for me. I am running Ubuntu 22.04. This is for the Goodix fingerprint device (ID: 27c6:550a)

Thank you! Turns out the fingerprint scanner was recognized from the beginning, just under the manufacturer name - there was no indication that it was a fingerprint scanner. :/ After that, installing fprintd and enrolling the fingerprint via fprintd-enroll worked for me.

If you're using Ubuntu 22.04 or newer, you can download the ELAN fingerprint driver from the Lenovo Support website - this should work: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds560939-elan-fingerprint-driver-for-ubuntu-2204-thinkpad-e14-gen-4-e15-gen-4

Thank you! Turns out the fingerprint scanner was recognized from the beginning, just under the manufacturer name - there was no indication that it was a fingerprint scanner. :/ After that, installing fprintd and enrolling the fingerprint via fprintd-enroll worked for me.
